# I send data as props to components. But, only the last component showing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to build a food web app. I wanted to fetch data from api and send to different components. When components will be clicked they will show data according to the props send to them.

But, **here the problem is only the last component is showing data. others are not.**

Image1(Home.js)
[image: Home.js]
Image2(Home.js-remaining)
[image: Home.js- remaining]
Image3(Breakfast component)
[image: Breakfast component]
Image4(Lunch Component)
[image: Lunch Component]
Image5(Dinner component)
[image: Dinner Component]
Image6(Output1)
[image: Here breakfast's data is showing in console. But, in UI breakfast data is not showing]
Image7(Output2)
[image: Here Lunch's data is showing in console. But, in UI Lunch data is not showing]
Image8(Output3)
[image: Here Dinner's data is showing perfectly.]

Comment: Coud you post actual code (instead of pictures) ? In way that your problem could be reproducible.

Comment: Please don't paste pictures it is difficult to debug and also  for fetching stuff use react-query .

Answer (score 2):

Ok so a few things:

1. Post your actual code, not *pictures* of code
2. The `.map` function if for **building** a new array, it's not really meant for looping over an array, use something like `.forEach` for that
3. Each `.map` iteration you're calling `setBreakfast` (or one of the other ones) and *overwriting* the previous state value. You want to build an **array** and set the state to that array
4. As a general rule don't update React state in a loop, it's inefficient and can causes issues. Run a loop to build a value/data structure, then set the state to that

What you want to do it something like this:

```
.then(
    setBreakfast(data.map(food => food.breakfast));
    setLunch(data.map(food => food.lunch));
    setDinner(data.map(food => food.dinner));
);
```

That way you're setting the state value to the return value of `.map`, which is an array containing all the corresponding meal values for that meal type.